# How to display latitude and longitude as two separate columns from current single with no separator?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, latitude-longitude

I have a data frame in Pandas with a column labeled “Location.”

The column is an object data type and is in the following format within the column:

Location

————————

POINT
(-73.525969

41.081897)

I’d like to remove the formatting and store each of the data points in two columns: Latitude and Longitude, which would have to be created. How would I accomplish this?

Similar post I’ve reviewed always have delimiters between the numbers (such as a comma) but this doesn’t.
Thank you!

Serial Number
List Year
Date Recorded
Town
Address
Assessed Value
Sale Amount
Sales Ratio
Property Type
Residential Type
Non Use Code
Assessor Remarks
OPM remarks
Location
0
141466
2014
2015-08-06
Stamford
83 OVERBROOK DRIVE
503270.0
850000.0
0.592082
Residential
Single Family
NaN
NaN
NaN
POINT (-73.525969 41.081897)
1
140604
2014
2015-06-29
New Haven
56 HIGHVIEW LANE
86030.0
149900.0
0.573916
Residential
Single Family
NaN
NaN
NaN
POINT (-72.878115 41.30285)
2
14340
2014
2015-07-01
Ridgefield
32 OVERLOOK DR
351880.0
570000.0
0.617333
Residential
Single Family
NaN
NaN
NaN
POINT (-73.508273 41.286223)
3
140455
2014
2015-04-30
New Britain
171 BRADFORD WALK
204680.0
261000.0
0.784215
Residential
Condo
NaN
NaN
NaN
POINT (-72.775592 41.713335)
4
141195
2014
2015-06-26
Stamford
555 GLENBROOK ROAD
229330.0
250000.0
0.917320
Residential
Single Family
NaN
NaN
NaN
POINT (-73.519774 41.07203)

Comment: What does `type(df['Location'].iloc[0])` return?

Comment: @Scott Boston it returns str

Comment: And also `print(df['Location'].iloc[0])`

Comment: Ah.. then we can use regex to parse out lat and long

Comment: Can you add a few more records to this question and I am sure @mozway can give you the answer in about two minutes. :-)?

Comment: @ScottBoston we might never know what is the separator ;)

Comment: @vudataanalyst please provide **text**. An image is not giving real information

Comment: @mozway My apologies. I added text from the df. As you may be able to tell, I'm very new to this :)

Comment: OK, then I expect my answer should work. Please check the tutorial on formatting and try to clean your question (you can export your data as dict with `dataframe.to_dict()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['Location'].str.extract('POINT \((?P<latitude>[-\d.@+])\s+(?P<longitude>[-\d.@+])\)').astype(float)
```

You might need to change the `\s+` separator depending on your real input

Comment: @ScottBoston I am not using linkedin, give me an address if you want me to contact you, I'll send you an email.